# Embedded image in portable area not showing on deployment

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-routing, portability, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am using MVC 2 on VS2010 and IIS 7. I created a portable area with some images embedded into it. I tried to create routing rule two ways at the time of portable area registeration. Following are the two ways I tried.

**Method 1**

```
    context.MapRoute("ResourceRoute", "login/resource/{resourceName}",
        new { controller = "EmbeddedResource", action = "Index" },
        new string[] { "MvcContrib.PortableAreas" });

        context.MapRoute(
            "login",
            "login/{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "login", action = "index" });

     RegisterAreaEmbeddedResources();
```

In this case I tried to access the image using Url.Resource()

**Method 2**

```
     context.MapRoute(
        "login",
        "login/{controller}/{action}",
        new { controller = "login", action = "index" });

     RegisterDefaultRoutes(context);
     RegisterAreaEmbeddedResources();
```

In this case I tried to access the image using Url.Content()

Following are scenarios where things are working fine.

1. When I run the application on my local development server (Ctrl + F5).
2. When run application after publishing it on my localhost.
3. When I run the application on different development server (Ctrl + F5), say on my friend's box.

But it does not render image (right now I have only images as static resource. No CSS or JS) if I publish on someone else's system, say localhost on my friend's box. Everything else is working fine except for the image rendering.

I have tried all possible means to get it rendered in the situation it is failing but all in vain. I need some help here. Anyone please?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There is a good discussion on how to handle embedded content in portable areas in this [blog post](http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2010/04/05/mvc-portable-areas-ndash-static-files-as-embedded-resources.aspx).